# AutocCompleteBox acting weird, wrong position of the dropbox menu

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to use the AutoCompleteBox control by the Windows Phone Toolkit. but its acting weird, its like this:

[image]

this is my xaml code:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="search">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="What?" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Width="350" Height="80" TextChanged="txtWhat_TextChanged" x:Name="txtWhat" />
                    <Button Width="75" x:Name="search" Click="search_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Where?" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtWhere" />
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Its funny that to get an item I have to click right above the textbox itself.
I've also tested it on the device. got the same screen
am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a common bug in the toolkit, we CANT use AutoCompleteBox inside a pivot, panorama or ScrollViewer :(  http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7574

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a scroll viewer on the page, so it can't scroll the control to the top of the screen to put the auto complete area below it. So it had to put it somewhere else? Try adding a scroll viewer (just outside the outer stack panel?) and that might solve your issue.

Comment: what do you mean by a scroll panel? scrollViewer?

Comment: @user836252 yes, a scroll viewer. Updated.